# Firebase & javascript - exclude items from one list to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having a mind blank here. What I have is 2 arrays:

1. A list of all users of the app
2. A list of all users of this form

What I want to do is return the difference between array 1 and 2.

Here is my list of all users of the app:

```
[{0: 
{id: 1234, email: test@test.com}
},{1:
{id: 1235, email: michael@test.com}
}]
```

Then array 2 would look like:

```
[{0: 
{id: 1234, email: test@test.com}
}]
```

So I want an array which would return (difference between array 1 and 2):

```
[{0:
{id: 1235, email: michael@test.com}
}]
```

Here is how I generate array 1:

```
this.allUsersList = [];

this.sharingProvider.getUsersListRef().on('child_added', userSn => {

  if(userSn.key) {
    this.allUsersList.push({
      id: userSn.key,
      email: userSn.val().email
    });
  }

});
```

And here is how i generate array 2:

```
this.sharingList = [];
this.sharingProvider.getFormsUsersRef(this.formId).on('child_added', fuSnap => {
  this.sharingProvider.getUsersListRef().child(fuSnap.key).on('value', userSn => {

    const myUserId = this.sharingProvider.getMyUserId();
    if(userSn.key !== myUserId) {
      this.sharingList.push({
        id: userSn.key,
        email: userSn.val().email
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  [some and Foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) ...

```js
let array1 = [
{0: 
{id: 1234, email: 'test@test.com'}
},
{1:
{id: 1235, email: 'michael@test.com'}
}
]

let array2 = [
{0: 
{id: 1234, email: 'test@test.com'}
}
],array3 = [];


array1.forEach(function(e){
  let conditional = array2.some(function(element,i){ 
  return e[i] && element[i].id === e[i].id && element[i].email === e[i].email
  });
  
  if(!conditional) array3.push(e);
});

console.log(array3);
```